# pthreads fill buffer in unexpected way

Tags: c, tcp, pthreads, client, buffer

I am trying to fill a buffer using `pthreads` in a simple TCP/IP server client communication.

**ATTENTION**: *Client writes its contents to an external server-address (not mine) and server reads its contents from an external client. The client and server that I have put below, do not communicate with each other.*

The buffer is filled in two ways:

1. Server reads a message and puts it into the buffer
2. Client creates a message and puts it into the buffer

Here is the **client function**:

```
void *client(void *threadid)
{
  //CLIENT INITIALIZATION AND CONNECT TO SERVER PROPERLY
  //sleep(1);   //sleep 1 second before you send again
  char *buff = "message1";   //message1,2,3 etc is defined by a random function

  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

  write(sockfd, buff, strlen(buff)+1);

  buffer_fill(buff);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
 }
```

And here is the **server function**. **Server reads from an external device that runs the same client code with me**:

```
void *server(void *threadid)
{
  //SERVER INITIALIZATION USING THE PROPER PORT AND ADDRESS
  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  bzero(buff, MAX_LENGTH);
  // read the message from client and copy it in buffer
  while(strlen(buff) == 0){
    read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
  }
  buffer_fill(buff);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I am using a simple `pthread`  initialization in my `main` function. So I am calling each function through the utilization of a thread:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
  int rc[NUM_THREADS];
  long t;

  for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){

    //initiallize thread
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
        return 1;
    }


    //create each thread according to value of t
    if(t==0){
      rc[t] = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, server, (void *)t);
    }else if(t==1){
      rc[t] = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, client, (void *)t);
    }

  }

  pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
  pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

  /* Last thing that main() should do */
  pthread_exit(NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

I assume the problem lies somewhere in the use of the (extremely simple) `buffer_fill(char *message)` in combination with the threads (***note : msg is a global variable initialized to zero outside main,*** `int msg = 0`):

```
void buffer_fill(char *m){

  if (msg<=MAX_MESSAGES){
    buffer[msg] = m;
    msg ++;
  }
  print_buffer();
}
```

When I execute this code continuously I get that kind of result:

```
first print:
message2

second print:
message1
message1

third print:
message5
message5
message5
```

and so on.

- Note that messages[1:5] are been selected randomly by the client and do not affect the outcome
- I assure you that the server client set up is correct. I checked it
  before writing the code that fills the buffer

Why is it that messages print like that and not in a serial form? I want every random message that is going to be written by client and every message that is read by the server to be stacked on buffer one after the other like this:

```
first print:
message2

second print:
message2
message1

third print:
message2
message1
message5
```

Comment: To be more specific, as I debug my code I can see that the problem lies somewhere on the fact that when I try to write to buffer through `msg` as an index (msg is a global variable) I don't change the contents: `buffer[msg]` only,  but the whole `buffer[0:msg]` .

Comment: If you're using TCP sockets, you have some serious problems - TCP sockets are streams with no concept of message boundaries.  When you `write()` a string to the socket, the other end can `read()` all or part of that string - and and it can also read **more than one string** (or **parts of more than one string**) if one has already been sent.  The best you can say about the code you posted is you haven't observed it breaking **yet**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you problem happens here

```
void buffer_fill(char *m){

  if (msg<=MAX_MESSAGES){
    buffer[msg] = m; // where
    msg ++;
  }
  print_buffer();
}
```

you should copy the value to `buffer` from `m` using `strcpy` or using a loop.

Edit: `char *` <=> `const char *` you should create an array or dynamically allocate the buffer.

Comment: `strcpy(buffer[msg], m)` produces me a segmentation fault error. Should I `buffer[msg] = malloc(strlen(m))` before the `strcpy`?

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer. Other answers (even from "big reputation" guys) were so irrelevant. You were right on spot!

Comment: You should use a safer version of strcpy (strcpy_s) and make sure you dont overflow the destination buffer.